# What is the best practice to expand GCE root persistent disk size of the running instance

Tags: postgresql, database-design, scalability, google-compute-engine

I'm running an instance for PostgreSQL whose disk size is 10G and it is almost full now.

Creating a new instance for PostgreSQL with the larger disk could be an option, but it will take so much time to change db setting stuffs on other instances I think.

Is there any best practice to expand disk size of the running instance with minimizing the downtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you can keep the db cluster **as is** an add a new [**`TABLESPACE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/manage-ag-tablespaces.html). The directory used should lie on a separate disk for best performance. This does not impose *any* downtime.

Not sure how this applies to Google Compute Engine. The "separate disk" aspect is hardly applicable for a cloud service. It might be possible to just increase the space available without any changes to the Postgres installation itself. That's something Google should tell you - you are paying for their service.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE space2 LOCATION '/path/to/postgres/data';
```

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/manage-ag-tablespaces.html)

> The location must be an existing, empty directory that is owned by the
>   PostgreSQL operating system user. All objects subsequently created
>   within the tablespace will be stored in files underneath this directory.

You can then create new objects (tables, indices, ..) or whole databases in the new tablespace, or move objects there with `ALTER` commands. Tablespaces are global objects and shared by all databases in a cluster:

> Once created, a tablespace can be used from any database, provided the
>   requesting user has sufficient privilege.

Typically, this layout is even faster than moving your instance to a single new disk (unless your current disk is substantially slower), because Postgres can profit from the combined I/O of two (or more) disks.

Be sure to read about details in the manual, particularly about the [default tablespace](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DEFAULT-TABLESPACE).

Answer (score 0):

You can take the snapshot of your disk. Than create a bigger disk with that snapshot. Finally create an instance with that bigger disk.

You can refer to the following article for more info
https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#creating_snapshots

Comment: Can I assign the same network-ip of the previous instance to a new instance with the bigger disk?

Comment: In order to have static IP for that instance you need to reserve an IP for  your project and than you will be able to assign that IP to the instance. However, reserving and IP cost extra. You can find more info on the following article https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#staticnetworkaddress

Comment: I would advise against that. Better solution is to attach another disk to running instance and move postgresql data to that new disk.